# The necessity of using ”init --bare” when sharing a repository in Git

Tags: git, github, version-control

In order to share repository and develop the same project with different members,
I have tried two ways to share:

(Method 1) Create a repository  in Github, then ask members to clone that specific repository  in there own local computer.

(Method 2) Git intialization with "--bare", then set the remote path the same as the created Github repository  path.
           Then ask members to clone the Github repository .

With both methods, one can successfully excute pull/add/commit/push commands. 
That is, the repository is shared to the members.

By doing so, I just became confused with the necessity of using "init --bare" when sharing a repository in Git,
because it seemed that I still can create shared repository without using "init --bare" commands.

Since lot of information I gatherd all saied that "init --bare" is for sharing repository,
my question is that "without using bare commands, a shared repository still can be created, then why do we use init --bare" ?

If ther is any concept I mistook, or if there is any better suggestion, please also inform me.

Thank you very much.

**2016/08/09 Added:**

I conducted two experiments: Case One [init] and Case Two [init --bare].

Although I tried to do the similar way to create shared repositories,
it seemed unsuccessful with Case One [init].

```
----------------Case One [init]----------------
(create shared_repo)
[/home/huang]$ mkdir git_repo_shared
[/home/huang/git_repo_shared]$ cd git_repo_shared
[/home/huang/git_repo_shared]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/huang/git_repo_shared/.git/

(User 1)
[/home/huang/git_repo_shared]$ cd ..
[/home/huang]$ mkdir User1
[/home/huang]$ cd User1
[/home/huang/User1]$ git clone /home/huang/git_repo_shared
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/huang/User1/git_repo_shared/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

(User 2)
[/home/huang/User1]$ cd ..
[/home/huang]$ mkdir User2
[/home/huang]$ cd User2
[/home/huang/User2]$ git clone /home/huang/git_repo_shared
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/huang/User2/git_repo_shared/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

(The revision made by User1 can syncronize to User2's folder)
[/home/huang/User2]$ cd ~/User1/git_repo_shared
[/home/huang/User1/git_repo_shared]$ echo test_user1 > test_user1.txt
[/home/huang/User1/git_repo_shared]$ git add test_user1.txt


[/home/huang/User1/git_repo_shared]$ git commit -m "test_user1.txt"
[master (root-commit) ae09328] test_user1.txt
 Committer: huang <huang@test-git-a.c.exture-analysis.internal>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

If the identity used for this commit is wrong, you can fix it with:

    git commit --amend --author='Your Name <you@example.com>'

 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test_user1.txt


[/home/huang/User1/git_repo_shared]$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 244 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/huang/git_repo_shared
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/huang/git_repo_shared'

$ cd ~/User2/git_repo_shared/
$ git pull origin master
$ ls


----------------Case Two [init --bare]----------------
(create shared_repo)
[/home/huang]$ mkdir git_repo_shared_bare
[/home/huang]$ cd git_repo_shared_bare
[/home/huang/git_repo_shared_bare]$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/huang/git_repo_shared_bare/

(User 3)
[/home/huang/git_repo_shared_bare]$ cd ..
[/home/huang]$ mkdir User3
[/home/huang]$ cd User3
[/home/huang/User3]$ git clone /home/huang/git_repo_shared_bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/huang/User3/git_repo_shared_bare/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

(User 4)
[/home/huang/User3]$ cd ..
[/home/huang]$ mkdir User4
[/home/huang]$ cd User4
[/home/huang/User4]$ git clone /home/huang/git_repo_shared_bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/huang/User4/git_repo_shared_bare/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

(The revision made by User3 can syncronize to User4's folder)
[/home/huang/User4]$ cd ~/User3/git_repo_shared_bare
[/home/huang/User3/git_repo_shared_bare]$ echo test_user3 > test_user3.txt
[/home/huang/User3/git_repo_shared_bare]$ git add test_user3.txt


[/home/huang/User3/git_repo_shared_bare]$ git commit -m "test_user3.txt"
[master (root-commit) 889a5c3] test_user3.txt
 Committer: huang <huang@test-git-a.c.exture-analysis.internal>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

If the identity used for this commit is wrong, you can fix it with:

    git commit --amend --author='Your Name <you@example.com>'

 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test_user3.txt


[/home/huang/User3/git_repo_shared_bare]$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 242 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To /home/huang/git_repo_shared_bare
 * [new branch]      master -> master

[/home/huang/User3/git_repo_shared_bare]$ cd ~/User4/git_repo_shared_bare
[/home/huang/User4/git_repo_shared_bare]$ git pull origin master
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From /home/huang/git_repo_shared_bare
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
[/home/huang/User4/git_repo_shared_bare]$ ls
test_user3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much a necessity as an opportunity. We know that we do not *need* the checked-out working directory for a repository that is simply used as a sharing medium (like a common team "push/pull" repository, or a Github hosted repository), so we skip it.

It may not make much difference now, but if you have many repositories on some sharing host, then it may pile up. And it's not just the saved HDD space, but since the working directory is absolutely never used/looked at, it's just completely avoidable.

So, in short, you're over-thinking it. :)

Comment: Thank you. I have added my experiments result. See the "2016/08/09 Added" section. It seemed init without "--bare" will fail. And I think the point here is that all the repositories in Github are bare repositories, that's why I was confused. (I have tried normal init, and then upload to github. At this moment, all the other users who tried to clone the repository in Github are cloning a "bare repository")

Answer (score 0):

1. A bare repo has no work tree, which means we cannot run `git checkout` in a bare repo. Thus a lot of disk space can be saved.
2. By default, we cannot push to update a remote ref which has been checked out because it's unsafe.